# Node Exporter Basic Auth (docker-compose)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I want to set up node exporter on my server to be monitored using docker compose but do not want the metrics to be freely available to all.

My current `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this;

```yaml
version: '3.8'

networks:
  monitoring:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  prometheus_data: {}

services:
  node-exporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter:latest
    container_name: node-exporter
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /proc:/host/proc:ro
      - /sys:/host/sys:ro
      - /:/rootfs:ro
    command:
      - '--path.procfs=/host/proc'
      - '--path.rootfs=/rootfs'
      - '--path.sysfs=/host/sys'
      - '--collector.filesystem.mount-points-exclude=^/(sys|proc|dev|host|etc)($$|/)'
      - '--collector.netclass.ignored-devices=^(veth.*)$$'
    ports:
      - 9100:9100
    networks:
      - monitoring
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"
```

When I add the following line to my `docker-compose.yml` file, I get error message below.

```yaml
    basic_auth_users:
      prometheus: my_pass
```

> services.node-exporter Additional property basic_auth_users is not allowed.

Can someone please help me where I am making mistakes or how the whole thing would work?

Ps: I would like to install on the server to be monitored only Node-Exporter since a Prometheus instance is not necessary there.... (Correct me if it is wrong approach)

Best regards

Comment: `basic_auth_users` **isn't** part of the `docker-compose.yml` syntax. It should form part of e.g. `web.yml` file that you mount into `node_exporter` service. If it were located on the host's working directory you could add a `volumes` of `${PWD}/web.yml:/web.yml` and then add to `command` another item `--web.config=/web.yml`

Comment: Thank you for info. I add this line ./prometheus/web.yml:/etc/prometheus/web.yml in to docker compose file under volumes and this - '--web.config=/etc/prometheus/web.yml' under command and it's working.

Answer (score 3):

### Answer:

Your problem is `basic_auth_users` **is not valid** sub-element of `services` element in `docker compose file`

You could check detail in [document](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/) of compose file

### Solution:

If you want to set basic auth for `node-exporter` by using image `prom/node-exporter:latest` in `docker-compose`, you should mount volume with basic auth config

Example:

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3'
services:
  node_exporter:
    image: quay.io/prometheus/node-exporter:latest
    container_name: node_exporter
    command: 
      - "--path.rootfs=/host"
      - "--web.config.file=/etc/prometheus/web.yml"  # --> set config file
    ports:
      - 9100:9100
    pid: host    
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - '/:/host:ro,rslave'
      - ./config/web.yml:/etc/prometheus/web.yml # --> mount config file
```

*web.yml*

```
basic_auth_users:
  <your_username>: <your_password>
```

### Another option:

If you prefer to configure basic authentication through environment variables rather than using a mounted volume in `docker-compose`, you may want to consider using a different image.

I have built an docker image for this option `vuongtlt13/node_exporter`

Example:

```
version: '3'
services:
  node_exporter:
    image: vuongtlt13/node_exporter
    container_name: node_exporter
    command:
      - "--path.rootfs=/host"
    ports:
      - 9100:9100
    pid: host
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - '/:/host:ro,rslave'
    environment:
      - BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME=admin
      - BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD=admin
```

Comment: Please make sure your are adding disclosure when linking to your own content. See [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

Comment: tks, i updated for more details. Sorry for my lazy :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution -> docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

networks:
  monitoring:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  prometheus_data: {}

services:
  node-exporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter:latest
    container_name: node-exporter
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /proc:/host/proc:ro
      - /sys:/host/sys:ro
      - /:/rootfs:ro
      - ./prometheus/web.yml:/etc/prometheus/web.yml
    command:
      - '--path.procfs=/host/proc'
      - '--path.rootfs=/rootfs'
      - '--path.sysfs=/host/sys'
      - '--collector.filesystem.mount-points-exclude=^/(sys|proc|dev|host|etc)($$|/)'
      - '--collector.netclass.ignored-devices=^(veth.*)$$'
      - '--web.config=/etc/prometheus/web.yml'
    ports:
      - 9100:9100
    networks:
      - monitoring
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a clean way to do it using only the `docker-compose.yml` and `.env` files:

*.env*

```
# Node Exporter credentials for basic-auth
EXPORTER_USERNAME='my_username'
EXPORTER_PASSWORD_HASH='my_super_secret_password'
```

*docker-compose.yml*

```yaml
node-exporter:
  ...
  entrypoint: >
    /bin/sh -c "
    mkdir -p /home/node-exporter;
    echo -e 'basic_auth_users: \\n  ${EXPORTER_USERNAME}: ${EXPORTER_PASSWORD_HASH}' > /home/node-exporter/web_config.yml;
    /bin/node_exporter --web.config.file='/home/node-exporter/web_config.yml'
    "
```

This solution overwrites the Node Exporter entrypoint, but invokes it again after creating the basic-auth configuration YAML file.

In case you are wondering, the `\\n` is used to do a newline.